# Pre-Padded Flooring

Tags: vinyl-flooring, underlayment

I am looking to install vinyl flooring in our basement which comes with pad attached. Can I use an additional pad?

Lots of research is finding conflicting answers, as well as from salesman from different sources all saying opposite things. Does anyone have any advice or experience with this.

Comment: I imagine this is floating vinyl planks, if so extra padding might not be good, unless quite thin.  The thin foam type padding for vinyl floors might be okay, but seems a waste of money and time.  What does the flooring installation instructions say.  They are what is the most important, not what people say.

Comment: If there's a warranty/guarantee, it surely depends on following the installation instructions.